# JQuery: how to make this variable negative before declaring it as a CSS value?

Tags: jquery, css

```
var footerheight = $("footer").height();
$("#body2").css("padding-bottom",footerheight);
$("footer").css("margin-top",footerheight);
$("footer").css("height",footerheight);
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#body2").paddingBottom("auto");
    var footerheight = $("footer").height();
    $("#body2").css("padding-bottom",footerheight);
    $("footer").css("margin-top",footerheight);
    $("footer").css("height",footerheight);
    });
```

The "footerheight" variable needs to be made negative before it is inputted as the "margin-top" value of the footer's styling. How is this done?

Comment: Why not just write `-footerheight` ? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything, I'm just an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.css('key',num)` just accepts a number.

So you can just do this:

```
var footerheight = -$("footer").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("footer").css("margin-top",footerheight*-1);
```

Multiply it by `-1`.

Comment: Nvm see Amit's answer